# Is there any API to download NSF file?

Tags: websphere, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

On the IBM WebSphere is there any API to download NSF-file from the server?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged this as a WebSphere question, I will answer for Java.

Yes, the [Database class](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_NOTESDATABASE_CLASS_JAVA.html) in the [Domino Java/CORBA API](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_JAVA_NOTES_CLASSES_JAVA.html) has methods [createCopy](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_CREATECOPY_METHOD_JAVA.html) and [createReplica](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_CREATEREPLICA_METHOD_JAVA.html) that can be used to effectively download an NSF file from a Domino server.